# How to bypass mempool

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, pending-transactions

I always see a mark on etherscan called "Private Transaction - this tx bypassed the mempool." What is happening there and how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

> What is happening there and how does it work?

One of two things is happening:

1. The miner is mining their own transactions;
2. A user/bot is sending their transaction to a private/permissioned mempool belonging to a specific miner.

Private mempools are a paid service. They're also not necessarily a pool, but an endpoint that is provided by the miner to clients who have paid for it.

You'll have to hunt around for such services online.

A good start to understanding how they work is described in [Escaping the Dark Forest](https://samczsun.com/escaping-the-dark-forest/).

Comment: Also see https://flashbots.org